# Android: layout issue with Image Views

Tags: android

I am keeping three image views with 3 different images of the same height. My code is as mentioned below..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stopServiceButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stop_service_button_selector" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calibrateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calibrate_button_selector" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/doneButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/done_button_selector" />


</LinearLayout>
```

In large layouts i was able to manage these images(i dont have to use weight parameter for it) but for small layout i have to keep the weight parameter as one to fit them in the screen, but then the height changes as shown below.
[image]

Can someone help me out in this ?

Comment: why are you using android:src to add the background? try using android:background

Comment: check by replacing all imageview width to fillparent and weight 1

Comment: yea, changing to background worked but the text in the image got blurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the  android:adjustViewBounds="true" preserves the aspect ratio of the images. since the width is to wrap content, the height gets reduced accordingly.

Comment: yea.. it preserves the aspect ratio.. but my basic problem was the weights which i did not give properly... :)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the blurring effect that you mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873445/android-layout-issue-with-image-views#comment12590986_9873445), you can try setting [`android:filter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android:filter) the attribute to the drawables.